# Gparted is not giving me the option to resize primary drive

Tags: 14.04, gparted, hyper-v

I am new to ubuntu and I'm trying to get my drive to resize. I am running on HyperV 2012 and have booted with the Gparted iso.

I do not have the option to resize the /dev/sda5. If I select /dev/sda2 I get no options to resize. Am I suppose to do something with the unallocated area first?

I probably am not doing this in the right order but can someone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the partition and select unmount before trying to make changes to it. When it shows a padlock/set of keys etc icon on the entry, it is mounted by the machine so changes cannot be applied to it.

When you have chosen what operations you want done, click the green tick button on the top bar to apply changes - Note data can be lost when applying changes so a backup of important data beforehand is highly recommended.

Documentation on GParted is [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/documentation.php) if you need it ([this bit](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-unmount-partition) specifically)

Comment: Unmount /dev/sda2? If so, then unmount is greyed out for me

Comment: this gave me pretty much what I needed, I had to deactivate the drive then extend it and it worked. Thanks for the help!